# Characterising mechanisms responsible for generating structural variants

Tags: bioinformatics, cancer, genomics

I have a high-quality set of structural variant breakpoints from tumour/normal WGS data, and I am interested in digging into the various mechanisms that might be involved in each event.

There are several mechanisms that are proposed to play a role in generating structural variants, including Non-allelic homologous recombination (NAHR), non-homologous end joining (NHEJ/MMEJ), alternative end joining (Alt-EJ) and several replicative mechanisms such as Fork Stalling and Template Switching (FoSTeS/MMBIR).

Each of these are distinct processes, that have occur at different time points in the cell cycle and have different potential for generating genomic rearrangements. However, I have not been able to find a consistent requirement for each mechanism.
I would like to know if anyone can think of a authoritative source for criteria I could use to form a working hypothesis as to the mechanism underlying each variant.

For example, if I have a 10 Kb deletion with 4 bases of microhomolgy at breakpoints I'm currently classifying it as an Alt-EJ event (largely based on the criteria I list below).

**Several specific questions:**
Microhomology at breakpoints is an essential requirement for several of these mechanisms (FoSTes/MMBIR). However, there appears to be no consensus as to whether this must occur exactly at the breakpoint, or whether it can be several bases away (for example [here](https://www.nature.com/articles/nrc3537.pdf)).

Secondly, according to [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3704973/) paper, the criterial used to classify structural variants is as follows (taken from the MeerKat manual):
**NAHR**: non-allellic homologous recombination, >100bp homology.
**alt-EJ**: alternative end joining, 3-100bp homology.
**NHEJ**: non-homologous end joining, 0-2bp homology or 1-10bp insertion at deletion break point.
**FoSTeS**: fork stalling and template switching, template switch, >10bp insertion at deletion break points.

However, almost every paper I read suggests different criteria, for example FoSTes events are normal associated with microhomologies at breakpoints rather than insertions.

Can anyone suggest a "consensus" of requirements for each mechanism?